# Search and filter a json response and reload collection view

Tags: json, swift, search, filter

I have a json data response as follows:

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "message": "Successfull",
    "mountingList": [
        {
            "$id": "2",
            "settingId": 2678941,
            "vendorId": "2906",
            "name": "ENGAGEMENT RING",
            "imageUrl": "https://www.gemfind.net/jewelryimages/2906/media/productimages/50973-e.jpg",
            "cost": 1092.0,
            "centerStoneMinCarat": "0.66",
            "centerStoneMaxCarat": "1.14",
            "originalCost": "",
            "mainImageURL": "https://www.gemfind.net/jewelryimages/2906/media/productimages/50973-e.jpg",
            "roundImageURL": "",
            "asscherImageURL": "",
            "emeraldImageURL": "",
            "radiantImageURL": "",
            "cushionImageURL": "",
            "marquiseImageURL": "",
            "ovalImageURL": "",
            "heartImageURL": "",
            "pearImageURL": "",
            "princessImageURL": "",
            "dealerId": "2803",
            "stockNumber": "50973-E",
            "isFavorite": false,
            "favId": null,
            "designerLogo": "https://www.gemfind.net/ResizeLogo.aspx?img=http://gemfind.net/dealerid_display/dealerimages/886660384logo_500x500_Wbg.png&wi=200&hi=200",
            "currencyFrom": "USD",
            "currencySymbol": "US$",
            "metalTypes": [
                {
                    "$id": "3",
                    "metalType": "14K Rose Gold"
                },
                {
                    "$id": "4",
                    "metalType": "14K White Gold"
                },
                {
                    "$id": "5",
                    "metalType": "14K Yellow Gold"
                },
                {
                    "$id": "6",
                    "metalType": "18K Rose Gold"
                },
                {
                    "$id": "7",
                    "metalType": "18K White Gold"
                },
                {
                    "$id": "8",
                    "metalType": "18K Yellow Gold"
                },
                {
                    "$id": "9",
                    "metalType": "Platinum"
                }
            ],
            "collections": [
                {
                    "$id": "10",
                    "collectionName": "Bypass"
                },
                {
                    "$id": "11",
                    "collectionName": "Pave"
                }
            ],
            "allowableDiamondShapes": [
                {
                    "$id": "12",
                    "allowableDiamondShape": "Round"
                }
            ],
            "priceSettingId": 2681358,
            "videoURL": "https://www.overnightmountings.com/gemfind/library/Download_video_files_for_individual_styles/50973-E/50973-E.video.white.mp4",
            "showPrice": true
        },
        {
            "$id": "13",
            "settingId": 2683984,
            "vendorId": "2906",
            "name": "ENGAGEMENT RINGS BYPASS",
            "imageUrl": "https://www.gemfind.net/jewelryimages/2906/media/productimages/51129-e.jpg",
            "cost": 959.0,
            "centerStoneMinCarat": "0.45",
            "centerStoneMaxCarat": "2.15",
            "originalCost": "",
            "mainImageURL": "https://www.gemfind.net/jewelryimages/2906/media/productimages/51129-e.jpg",
            "roundImageURL": "",
            "asscherImageURL": "",
            "emeraldImageURL": "",
            "radiantImageURL": "",
            "cushionImageURL": "",
            "marquiseImageURL": "",
            "ovalImageURL": "",
            "heartImageURL": "",
            "pearImageURL": "",
            "princessImageURL": "",
            "dealerId": "2803",
            "stockNumber": "51129-E",
            "isFavorite": false,
            "favId": null,
            "designerLogo": "https://www.gemfind.net/ResizeLogo.aspx?img=http://gemfind.net/dealerid_display/dealerimages/886660384logo_500x500_Wbg.png&wi=200&hi=200",
            "currencyFrom": "USD",
            "currencySymbol": "US$",
            "metalTypes": [
                {
                    "$id": "14",
                    "metalType": "14K Rose Gold"
                },
                {
                    "$id": "15",
                    "metalType": "14K White Gold"
                },
                {
                    "$id": "16",
                    "metalType": "14K Yellow Gold"
                },
                {
                    "$id": "17",
                    "metalType": "18K Rose Gold"
                },
                {
                    "$id": "18",
                    "metalType": "18K White Gold"
                },
                {
                    "$id": "19",
                    "metalType": "18K Yellow Gold"
                },
                {
                    "$id": "20",
                    "metalType": "Platinum"
                }
            ],
            "collections": [
                {
                    "$id": "21",
                    "collectionName": "Bypass"
                },
                {
                    "$id": "22",
                    "collectionName": "Solitaire"
                }
            ],
            "allowableDiamondShapes": [
                {
                    "$id": "23",
                    "allowableDiamondShape": "Round"
                }
            ],
            "priceSettingId": 2688032,
            "videoURL": "https://www.overnightmountings.com/gemfind/library/Download_video_files_for_individual_styles/51129-E/51129-E.video.white.mp4",
            "showPrice": true
        },
        {
            "$id": "24",
            "settingId": 2684001,
            "vendorId": "2906",
            "name": "ENGAGEMENT RINGS TRELLIS",
            "imageUrl": "https://www.gemfind.net/jewelryimages/2906/media/productimages/82854-e.jpg",
            "cost": 731.0,
            "centerStoneMinCarat": "0.66",
            "centerStoneMaxCarat": "3.25",
            "originalCost": "",
            "mainImageURL": "https://www.gemfind.net/jewelryimages/2906/media/productimages/82854-e.jpg",
            "roundImageURL": "",
            "asscherImageURL": "",
            "emeraldImageURL": "",
            "radiantImageURL": "",
            "cushionImageURL": "",
            "marquiseImageURL": "",
            "ovalImageURL": "",
            "heartImageURL": "",
            "pearImageURL": "",
            "princessImageURL": "",
            "dealerId": "2803",
            "stockNumber": "82854",
            "isFavorite": false,
            "favId": null,
            "designerLogo": "https://www.gemfind.net/ResizeLogo.aspx?img=http://gemfind.net/dealerid_display/dealerimages/886660384logo_500x500_Wbg.png&wi=200&hi=200",
            "currencyFrom": "USD",
            "currencySymbol": "US$",
            "metalTypes": [
                {
                    "$id": "25",
                    "metalType": "14K Rose Gold"
                },
                {
                    "$id": "26",
                    "metalType": "14K White Gold"
                },
                {
                    "$id": "27",
                    "metalType": "14K Yellow Gold"
                },
                {
                    "$id": "28",
                    "metalType": "18K Rose Gold"
                },
                {
                    "$id": "29",
                    "metalType": "18K White Gold"
                },
                {
                    "$id": "30",
                    "metalType": "18K Yellow Gold"
                },
                {
                    "$id": "31",
                    "metalType": "Platinum"
                }
            ],
            "collections": [
                {
                    "$id": "32",
                    "collectionName": "Single Row"
                },
                {
                    "$id": "33",
                    "collectionName": "Trellis"
                }
            ],
            "allowableDiamondShapes": [
                {
                    "$id": "34",
                    "allowableDiamondShape": "Round"
                }
            ],
            "priceSettingId": 2688583,
            "videoURL": "https://www.overnightmountings.com/gemfind/library/Download_video_files_for_individual_styles/82854/82854.video.white.mp4",
            "showPrice": true
        },], }
```

I need to match the collection name which is given inside collections while searching,once matched i want to reload the collection view with the search data.

The search delegate method is as follows:

```
 func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
          
          if searchText.count <= 0 {
                 searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
              self.collectionview1.reloadData()
             }
          else
          {

          if let list3 = orgsearchDataModel?.mountingList.map( { $0.collections.filter {$0.collectionName.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil}})
            {
                 print("matched list is",list3)
                // ProductlistDataModelElement?.mountingList = list3
                //  self.collectionview1.reloadData()
            }
}
```

The orgsearchDataModel is the model class which shows all products in the collection view.
Now the above list3 result is not showing from root which is mountinglist. It is just showing the array from collections.

The print statement of list3 is as follows:
matched list is
[[AdamasIntl.Collection(id: "10", collectionName: "Bypass")], [AdamasIntl.Collection(id: "21", collectionName: "Bypass")], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]

I want to match the collection name and result it is show that particular array completely.I mean starting from the id, i want the complete array which matches.How to achieve it?

The model file is given below:

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - DiamondMainListModel
struct DiamondMainListModel: Codable {
    let id, message: String
    var mountingList: [MountingList]
    let count: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "$id"
        case message, mountingList, count
    }
}

// MARK: - MountingList
struct MountingList: Codable {
    let id: String
    let settingID: Int
    let vendorID, name: String
    let imageURL: String
    let cost: Int
    let centerStoneMinCarat, centerStoneMaxCarat, originalCost: String
    let mainImageURL: String
    let roundImageURL, asscherImageURL, emeraldImageURL, radiantImageURL: String
    let cushionImageURL, marquiseImageURL, ovalImageURL, heartImageURL: String
    let pearImageURL, princessImageURL, dealerID, stockNumber: String
    let isFavorite: Bool
    let favID: String?
    let designerLogo: String
    let currencyFrom: String?
    let currencySymbol: String?
    let metalTypes: [MetalTypeElement]
    let collections: [Collection]
    let allowableDiamondShapes: [AllowableDiamondShape]
    let priceSettingID: Int
    let videoURL: String
    let showPrice: Bool

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "$id"
        case settingID = "settingId"
        case vendorID = "vendorId"
        case name
        case imageURL = "imageUrl"
        case cost, centerStoneMinCarat, centerStoneMaxCarat, originalCost, mainImageURL, roundImageURL, asscherImageURL, emeraldImageURL, radiantImageURL, cushionImageURL, marquiseImageURL, ovalImageURL, heartImageURL, pearImageURL, princessImageURL
        case dealerID = "dealerId"
        case stockNumber, isFavorite
        case favID = "favId"
        case designerLogo, currencyFrom, currencySymbol, metalTypes, collections, allowableDiamondShapes
        case priceSettingID = "priceSettingId"
        case videoURL, showPrice
    }
}

// MARK: - AllowableDiamondShape
struct AllowableDiamondShape: Codable {
    let id, allowableDiamondShape: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "$id"
        case allowableDiamondShape
    }
}

// MARK: - Collection
struct Collection: Codable {
    let id, collectionName: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "$id"
        case collectionName
    }
}


// MARK: - MetalTypeElement
struct MetalTypeElement: Codable {
    let id: String
    let metalType: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "$id"
        case metalType
    }
}

enum MetalTypeEnum: String, Codable {
    case platinum = "Platinum"
    case the14KRoseGold = "14K Rose Gold"
    case the14KWhiteGold = "14K White Gold"
    case the14KYellowGold = "14K Yellow Gold"
    case the18KRoseGold = "18K Rose Gold"
    case the18KWhiteGold = "18K White Gold"
    case the18KYellowGold = "18K Yellow Gold"
}
```

The api method to fetch it is as follows:

```
    func getprofile()
       {
            
        AF.request("http://api.jewelcloud.com/api/RingBuilder/GetMountingList?DealerID=2803", method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { response in
         
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()

             do {
                
            
                let user = try decoder.decode(DiamondMainListModel.self, from: response.data!)
                self.ProductlistDataModelElement = user
                self.orgsearchDataModel = user
                if self.ProductlistDataModelElement!.count > 0{
                    
                    print("total no of ring products are",self.ProductlistDataModelElement?.mountingList.count)
                    
                    
                    for items in 0..<(self.ProductlistDataModelElement?.mountingList.count)!
                    {
                        
            
                        self.imagearray.append((self.ProductlistDataModelElement?.mountingList[items].imageURL)!)
                        
                        self.pricearray.append((self.ProductlistDataModelElement?.mountingList[items].cost) as! Int)
                        
                    }
                    

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    
                    self.loadingview.isHidden = true
                    self.loading.isHidden = true
                    self.collectionview1.delegate = self
                    self.collectionview1.dataSource = self
                    self.collectionview1?.reloadData()
                    }
                    

                 }
                 else
                 {
                     self.navigationController?.view.makeToast("No Products in this category", duration: 3.0, position: .center)
                     
                 }
                 
             } catch {
                  debugPrint(error)
               
             }
             
           }

       }
```

Comment: which objects Array ?

Comment: you are already getting id :) ..

Comment: you are getting collections object ...

Comment: See i have the array for  collection view which is orgsearchdatamodel.count.The search delegate over here is filtering bases on collection name and result is only from the collection array which is inside mountinglist array.I need the collection name to be matched and result should be mountinglist array and not collections array as per json response.

Comment: Don't use `map` then and filter directly on the original type. It is not easy to help when all we get to see is the json and not the actual type used in the code

Comment: I have the model json file.if its helpful.

Comment: What is the difference to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62517139/json-parsing-with-search-delegate-in-swift)? Rather than reposting questions add more relevant information

Comment: Yes i have added more info to it.So that i can be more clear on what i want

Comment: @JoakimDanielson have added more code to the question

Comment: @JoakimDanielson replacing the map with filter shows an error,as there is filter inside too.Basically i need to search by collection name and return the mountinglist array.

Comment: @jawadAli Have added extra code.Any help out of it?

Comment: I meant remove `map` and of course use only one filter but I understand now this question is a duplicate of your last one so you need to remove one of them.

Comment: Yes deleted that post.Hope now it can be answered

Comment: @JoakimDanielson i replaced map with filter as follows:   if let list3 = orgsearchDataModel?.mountingList.filter( { $0.collections.filter({$0.collectionName.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil})})   But it shows error saying Cannot convert value of type '[Collection]' to closure result type 'Bool'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter out the search term and keep the data structure you can do

```
mountingList.filter { !$0.collections.filter{$0.collectionName.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil}.isEmpty}
```